# How does Firefox decide what to do when navigating to offline file and no MIME is available?

Tags: firefox, download, mime-types

I am working on turning a part of a website into an simple offline application suitable to put on a memory stick. This involves saving all html, images and linked files and changing URLs so that they work in an offline context.

Some of the files included are .epub and .mobi files (different E-pub formats) while most are PDF files. For a colleague of mine (Win 7, FF 16.0.2), clicking links in the offline version to .epub and .mobi files displays their contents in the browser, while clicking the "same" link on the website triggers the normal open/save dialog. In my FF (Win 7,  FF 19.0), I get the dialog in both cases.

All info I have found about file handling in FF state that the action taken is solely based on which MIME type the web server serves the file with. For an "offline website" like ours, this obviously doesn't apply, as there is no web server involved. Does Firefox resort to inspecting the file suffix in this case, or does it rely on OS settings maybe? We are worried that other users may experience files opening in the browser.

Comment: Perhaps something changed in FF? Have you tested with same FF versions on different PCs? Are the epub/mobi reader FF plugins used by your colleague and you exactly the same?